Change file system access permissions for SSH via SSH
Mac OS has per-application file-system access rules:

While logged in graphically, the first time an application attempts to access certain locations, e.g. Desktop, a popup appears, prompting to allow / deny file system access.
The same settings can be edited in the UI in the system settings

I am looking for a way to change the settings remotely:

I am connected to a remote Mac, via VPN.
I have full root user SSH access, there is no firewall.
However, the remove Mac's privacy settings prevent me from accessing certain folders.

Is there a way to modify the access settings for SSH remotely ?

Wouldn't this break the additional security you get from having to approve such access once while logged in via GUI?
